# Listing the Files in a Directory WinApi

Tags: c++, file, winapi

In directories I have only 3 files (poem.txt , mac. txt , some_file.txt).

Why in my output 2 weird files with name "." and ".." ?

What is that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fileData;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(L"D:\\Univesity\\PROJECTS\\OS_Course\\poem_old\\*", &fileData);

    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            //wcout << fileData.cFileName << endl;
            WIN32_FIND_DATA compared_fileData;
            HANDLE compared_hFind = FindFirstFile(L"D:\\Univesity\\PROJECTS\\OS_Course\\poem2_new\\*", &compared_fileData);

            if (compared_hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                do {
                    //wcout << (wstring) fileData.cFileName << endl << (wstring) compared_fileData.cFileName;
                    if ( (wstring) fileData.cFileName == (wstring) compared_fileData.cFileName) {
                        FILETIME fileWriteTime = fileData.ftLastWriteTime;
                        FILETIME compared_fileWriteTime = compared_fileData.ftLastWriteTime;
                        /*
                            -1  First file time is earlier than second file time. 
                            0   First file time is equal to second file time. 
                            1   First file time is later than second file time. 
                        */
                        int comparationResult = CompareFileTime(&fileWriteTime, &compared_fileWriteTime);
                        if (comparationResult == 1) {
                            wcout << "Comparation: " << (wstring)fileData.cFileName << " is later than " << (wstring)compared_fileData.cFileName << endl;
                        }
                        else if (comparationResult == -1) {
                            wcout << "Comparation: " << (wstring)fileData.cFileName << " is earlier than " << (wstring)compared_fileData.cFileName << endl;
                        }
                    }
                } while (FindNextFile(compared_hFind, &compared_fileData));
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &fileData));
        FindClose(hFind);
    }
}
```

Output:

Comparation: . is later than .

Comparation: .. is later than ..

Comparation: black.txt is earlier than black.txt

Comparation: mac.txt is earlier than mac.txt

Comparation: some_file.txt is later than some_file.txt

Comment: In a command prompt type `dir`  .  `.` is the current directory and `..` is the parent directory.

Comment: Sidenote: Do you really need some of the special things in the WinAPI to do this? Why not use  `std::filesystem` (available since C++17)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I usually don’t use C ++, so I know little about it.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: `std::filesystem::diretory_iterator` could handle this particular case.  In general, however, it has a lot of compromises the boil down to being a least-common-denominator wrapper over Windows and Posix-style filesystems, making it hard to do things that the native APIs do, like consistent application of wildcards, handling long and 8.3 file names, and certain types of efficient searches.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Yeah, I know there are limitations but for the usual cases it does well. I do as much as possible with `std::filesystem` and only go native if needed, and only for the specific parts that actually need it. And in this Q, I saw no need.

Comment: @ted: You cannot see the input data (i.e. the file system contents) from the question. Maybe there is something, that `std::filesystem` won't handle, or handle in an unexpected way.

Comment: @IInspectable If it doesn't handle something the way the standard dictates, it's a bug and should be reported. Afaik the VS version of `std::filesystem` uses the native API, to fullfill what's demanded by the standard, so problems of that kind should be rare.

Comment: @ted: NTFS supports [3 types of file links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions). I wasn't referring to a non-conforming standard library implementation. I was referring to a standard library specification, that simply cannot deliver, except for the most trivial of cases. And even then you may find yourself surprised.

Comment: @IInspectable For normal filesystem operations, that's rarely something preventing one from starting to use `std::filesystem` and only go native when needed. If one intends to do something where `std::filesystem` can't even be used at top level, sure, skip it, but for this case I would certainly not expect `std::filesystem` to cause problems. Afaik, `follow_directory_symlink` works well with `recursive_directory_iterator` if that's needed.

Comment: @ted: My point is that filesystems vary too much across platforms, that something like *"normal operations"* simply does not exist. I've probably used all of C++, and `std::filesystem` is the only library I would always avoid.

Comment: @IInspectable We come at it from different angles then I guess. In most of the program's I've made, going native has not been necessary at the top level and `std::filesystem` has worked well, which then has been seen as _normal_ for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` and `..` are pseudo directories. The semantics are [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions):

> - Use a period as a directory *component* in a path to represent the current directory, for example ".\temp.txt". For more information, see [Paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#fully-qualified-vs-relative-paths).
> - Use two consecutive periods (..) as a directory *component* in a path to represent the parent of the current directory, for example "..\temp.txt". For more information, see [Paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#fully-qualified-vs-relative-paths).